# What character skill would be able to be used for medical/healing purposes?

Tags: character-creation, skills, dresden-files, healing

**For a character in the Dresden Files who is a doctor/medic, which of the Skills is supposed to actually be used/rolled on to try put that medical ability into use?**

For instance, I'd say *"scholarship"* would be a necessity to have statted at least at Good for a trained doctor - but would that be what you roll on, having to actually try heal someone/patch up a wound possibly right on a street, or would it be something else like "*survival"* you would use instead?

Or am I looking at this the wrong way entirely and it perhaps would be an *aspect* you invoke (e.g. along the lines of "is a doctor") and *not* a skill for this?

I feel there's got to be an answer to this somewhere in the rules - I just have not been able to find it.

Comment: Are you talking about healing NPCs or PCs?

Comment: @AllanMills oh! Are the answers different for NPCs or PCs? I didn't know and was thinking just ability in general (so either or).

Comment: Well, in FATE for PCs your stress damage ends after the conflict. It's only consequences that hang around. You can reduce them using the reiki healing spell but generally speaking FATE doesn't have much healing since it would defeat the purpose of receiving consequences. For an NPC though, unless they are a major character, they aren't really using a character sheet so they don't have stress or consequences to deal with. You might find an NPC with a broken arm though and make some kind of attempt to treat them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Doctor Stunt that will help you. From "Your Story", p 155

> Doctor (Specify): You have a medical degree or the equivalent of such an education. **You may use your Scholarship skill** to declare appropriate justification for the recovery of moderate physical consequences when outside a medical facility, and for the recovery of severe physical consequences within a medical facility. For research purposes, gain +1 on Scholarship for any medical research and an additional +1 in a specific area of medicine. This stunt may be taken twice, with the bonuses on research stacking to indicate particularly deep or excellent medical knowledge (such as with a heart surgeon, etc.).